# ¿Cómo buscar archivos por día de la semana?

Tags: bash, linux

Tengo que eliminar archivos comprimidos que son backups de nuestra Base de Datos siguiendo las dos siguientes reglas:

1. Deben ser de más de 15 días de antigüedad
2. No eliminar los backups de los días domingos

Decidí usar el comando `find`, creo que es el más completo de los comandos de búsqueda (por lo menos de los que conozco).

La primera regla es sencilla, usando el parámetro `-ctime` puedo encontrar los archivos con fecha de creación mayores a 15 días:

```
$ find /backups/db/ -type f -ctime +15 -name "*.sql.gz" 
./gestagro_2015_11_01.sql.gz
./gestagro_2015_11_02.sql.gz
./gestagro_2015_11_03.sql.gz
(varios resultados)
```

Luego, en el mismo `find` no encontré nada parecido en su `man` page con respecto a días de la semana. Lo más cercano que he estado hasta el momento es poder imprimir el nombre del archivo junto con su fecha formateada para que se muestre el día de la semana usando la acción `-printf`:

```
$ find /backups/db/ -type f -ctime +15 -name "*.sql.gz" -printf "%p %Aa\n"
./gestagro_2015_11_01.sql.gz dom
./gestagro_2015_11_02.sql.gz lun
./gestagro_2015_11_03.sql.gz mar
(varios resultados)
```

El problema ahora es que no se cómo volver a filtrar esos resultados para escoger aquellos que no son del día `dom` y luego aplicarles el `-delete`.

Estoy abierto a nuevas opciones, no necesariamente con el comando `find`, puede ser usando pipes o lo que funcione para este caso. Ayúdenme a ver la luz.

### Actualización

La respuesta de @Gilles me ayudó a encontrar el camino, sin embargo, tuve que modificar un poco la última parte. La sentencia final es la siguiente:

```
$ find /backups/db/ -type f -ctime +15 -printf '%p %Aa\n' | sed -e '/dom$/d' -e 's/ [^ ]+$//' | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Con pipes: filtramos los archivos del domingo, luego quitamos el día.

```
LC_TIME=es_ES find /backups/db/ -type f -ctime +15 -name "*.sql.gz" -printf '%p %Aa\0' |
sed -z -e '/dom$/d' -e 's/ [^ ]+$//' |
xargs -0 rm
```

Si usted tiene una versión vieja de `sed` que no tiene `-Z`, y no hay caracteres especiales (espacios, `\"'`) en los nombres de archivo:

```
LC_TIME=es_ES find /backups/db/ -type f -ctime +15 -name "*.sql.gz" -printf '%p %Aa\n' |
sed -e '/dom$/d' -e 's/ [^ ]+$//' |
xargs -0 rm
```

Otra opción es cambiar el nombre de los archivos para indicar el día de la semana.

Comment: Ya estoy cerca. Con la segunda opción me acerco mas, sin embargo lo de `xargs` no me funciona, me sale "no such file or directory". He modificado un poco el comando a: `find . -type f -ctime +15 -printf '%p %Aa\n' | sed -e '/Tue$/d' -e 's/ [^ ]+$//' | cut -d' ' -f1` pero me falta la última parte para eliminarlos.

Comment: Lo tengo. Ya no debo usar parámetros al final en `xargs` si estoy usando el comando `cut` antes. Comando final: `find /backups/db/ -type f -ctime +15 -printf '%p %Aa\n' | sed -e '/dom$/d' -e 's/ [^ ]+$//' | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs rm`. Gracias